# Are Electromagnetic Waves Independent from Their Source

Tags: special-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, relative-motion

Let's say we are on a latitude where the earth's rotation is 1,000 miles per hour. A rifle target is positioned a 1,000 yards away, perpendicular to the rotation. It's my understanding that a shooter does not need to allow for the earth's rotation, he can aim at the target, allow for drop, and if all goes well the target will be hit. No adjustments need to be made for the earth's rotation. The rifle, the air, the shooter, the bullet, the target all move together. I understand. What's perplexing to me is that the same is true for a laser. Wouldn't EM waves be independent from the earth's motion? Is there a relativity thing going on here? If a laser is pointed into a night sky is it traveling ahead at c and to the right or left at the earths rotation speed? If so can we measure the "sideways speed"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen from a reference frame not rotating with the Earth, the speed will still be $c$. However, say that the  photon was emitted, as seen moving with the Earth,   pointing vertically (radial direction) toward some remote star. The observer not rotating with the Earth will see the photon moving not in a radial direction, but in a direction at an angle with respect to the vertical. The angle is such that the velocity component in the tangential direction will be the earth's tangential speed, and the velocity magnitude will be $c$. If this were not the case then the two observers would disagree about the photon arriving or not to the distant star. The observer moving with the Earth sees himself pointing vertically and the distant star moving on a tangential direction opposite to Earth's rotation. So he sees that the photon will not reach the star. For the outside observer to reach the same conclusion, the photon must travel in a non radial direction, otherwise the photon would reach the star as this one is not moving on its reference frame.

Comment: Humm... I knew relativity affected time and length, but I was unaware that it affects direct too. Interesting.

Comment: It is not a relativistic effect, it happens in classical kinematics too. Think of an object thrown up from a moving car. The observer in the car sees it as moving up. An observer at rest with the floor will see it moving in a oblique direction.